# Autocatalysis / Electroless plating of mercury

Tags: electrolysis

As a project I am trying to plate mercury onto a powdered metal amalgam of $\ce{Cu}$ & $\ce{Ag}$. I am using solution of $\ce{HgCl2}$ in normal $\ce{HCl}$ (a reducing agent), Any thoughts for increasing the efficiency of plating process on the metal alloy powder? How can we improve the $\ce{Hg}$ plating on the metal powder? Can the concept of autocatalysis / electroless plating be helpful in this case?